# T is a linear transformation $T : M_{2x2}(R) \rightarrow M_{2x2}(R)$ and $T(a,b,c,d) = (a+b+c,2b+d,d,d)$ Find $[T]_e$ (include my solution)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have the following question :

T is a linear transformation $T : M_{2x2}(R) \rightarrow M_{2x2}(R)$

$B_{KerT} = Sp\{1,-1,0,0\}$

$B_{ImT} = Sp\{(1,0,0,0),(1,2,0,0),(0,1,1,1)\}$

**I'll work in $R^4$ for convenient.**

$$T(a,b,c,d) = (a+b+c,2b+d,d,d)$$

Find $[T]_e$ (while $e$ is the standard basis)

**My solution**

Okay so I need to find the following :

I know that $ImT+KerT=R^4$ from a theorem, therefore 
$$\{(1,0,0,0),(1,2,0,0),(0,1,1,1),(1,-1,0,0)\}$$ is a basis for $R^4$

Now I need to find using the basis above:

$T(e_1),T(e_2),T(e_3),T(e_4)$

Therefore :

$$T(e_1)=(1,0,0,0)=1(1,0,0,0)+0+0+0$$
$$T(e_2)=(1,2,0,0)=0+1(1,2,0,0)+0+0$$
$$T(e_3)=(1,0,0,0)=1(1,0,0,0)+0+0+0$$
$$T(e_4)=(0,1,1,1)=0+0+1(0,1,1,1)+0$$

Therefore :

$$[T]_e = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right)$$

For some reason in the answers they got different answer than mine.

I'd like to know if my solution is wrong since I think they have a mistake because I use the definition of representative matrix (I'm not sure if the right term in of $[T]_e$ in English if it isn't I apologize).

Any help will be dearly appreciated!, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement "$ImT+KerT=R^4$" is false, the correct statement is $ \dim ImT+\dim Ker T=\dim R^{4}=4$.
Therefore, you're not sure that $\{(1,0,0,0),(1,2,0,0),(0,1,1,1),(1,-1,0,0)\}$ is a base, and if you check, it isn't. There is your mistake.
Besides, why don't you use $e=\{(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1)\}$ as base? It would be simpler.

Comment: I checked and $ImT+KerT \neq R^4$ as you said now I'm out of ideas how to get to $[T]_e$ I need a basis in order to use the definition yet, I don't have one, Any ideas what could be done?

Comment: Well, I just edited the answer to cover this ^^

Comment: Oh, I feel really stupid for not thinking for that and not understanding the question this is what they asked in the question in the first place to use $$e=\{(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1)\}$$, instand I went to use the basis of ImT+KerT !?!?, Guess I'll take a few minute to refresh. Thank you for you help! all clear:)